# Using R + tm (text mining) library, I want to mash words together but not n-grams

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, tm

I am using R and the text mining library, `tm`.

I am looking at job postings gleaned from the biotech (i.e. bioinformatics jobs) websites, copied and pasted into .txt files. I am able to do a quick and dirty histogram and word cloud but the text mining is still showing me nothing new.

The word cloud shows the usual one word responses such as "molecular", "biology", etc.  I have also done a quick and dirty bi-gram of the job posting.  It gave to many ["in" + "vivo"] or  ["in" + "silico"] for example.  This is not useful tome.

1. I want to know how many times BS / MS/ PhD (for example) are shown in all the job posting.
2. I want to transform some words to mash ups.  Without going thru a tri-gram.

For example:
next generation sequencing -> NGS

I tried:

```
toMash <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {
                              return (gsub(pattern, nextGenerationSequencing, x))})

docs <- tm_map(docs, toMash, "next generation sequencing")
```

Comment: My sense is you need to focus more time on data cleaning prior to mapping. Without an example data file, it is tricky to provide a real example against actual data. My personal approach would be to spend some quality time on defining your own `stop words` list above and beyond the basic `docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))`. For example you could strip out the noise from the data `docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("molecular", "biology"))  ` I hope this helps.

Comment: This may be useful to you: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html

Comment: @Technophobe01 I really want to keep phrases like "molecular biology"  but the text analysis gets 'stuck' on the extraneous words, like 'familiarity with'. However, I think you are correct in that I need to pre-process more but not sure where to start.  The web page you listed is interesting and could be helpful. Let me check it over.

Comment: No worries - if you can provide an example data file then I should be able to provide a code example. My sense is you need to strip away some of the extraneous data in the files. I used `molecular` and `biology` by way of example only. `tm()` is super powerful - you'll love it.